# valuation on function fields

Tags: algebraic-geometry, function-fields

Let $p$ be an irreducible polynomial in $k[x]$, for some characteristic 0 field $k$. So we have a valuation $v_p$ corresponding to $p$. Now take $a$ to be a root of $p(x)$. Then $(x-a)$ is irreducible over $k(a)$, and $v_{x-a}$ is a place lying over $v_p$.

> What is the degree of the extension $\kappa(v_{x-a}) / \kappa(v_p)$?  (here $\kappa(-)$ denotes the residue field).

Comment: I don't know what this means. What you're doing, if I understand you correctly, is as follows. Consider $L=k[x]/(p(x))$, then $L[x]/k[x]$ is a finite extension of Dedekind domain. Moreover, $v_{x-a}$ is a place of $L[x]$ lying over $v_p$ in $k[x]$. What is $\kappa$? The function field? What is the function field of a valuation? Do you mea n the residue field?

Comment: Sorry, yes, I do mean the residue fields.

Comment: If it's in characteristic zero, then it's just $\deg p$, no?